# Differentiability in higher dimension

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that all its partial derivaties $f_x,f_y,f_{xy},f_{yx},f_{xx},f_{yy}$ exist and are continuous. I know that it implies that $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$.

I want to know does the above information also gives that, the existence of a second-order derivative (by which I mean the Frechet derivative) of $f$.

Please help me with the same.

Thanks.

Comment: But without the existence and continuity of $f_{xx}, f_{yy}$ I don't see why the second Frechet derivative should exist. If all partials up to second order exist and are continuous on an open set then the function is twice continuously Frechet differentiable on that open set.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I edited the question. Thanks again.

Comment: The case of continuity of first order partials implying continuously Frechet differentiable is a very classic theorem. The general case follows by induction (I suggest you write your attempted proof).